# prove group G possesses a simple quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, analysis

Zorn's lemma:
   If X is a partially ordered set under $\le$ and every totally ordered subset  has an upper bound, then X has a maximal element. (more specifically: check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma)

Let P denote the set of proper normal subgroups of G partially ordered by inclusion. Show that the hypothesis of Zorn's Lemma holds for P. Deduce that G possesses a simple quotient group.

I spent a long time in this question, but I am still stuck in it, can someone give me some help?

Comment: The partially order $\leq$ here is the subgroup relation. Zorn's Lemma gives a maximal subgroup of $G$. You want to show that this maximal subgroup is normal and the quotient of $G$ by it is simple.

Comment: sorry, there was some typing mistake, P should be the set of proper normal subgroups of G.

Answer (score 3):

The Pruefer groups are groups without a maximal subgroup (whence without a maximal normal subgroup, being abelian).  Therefore, these groups have no simple quotients.

Comment: sorry, there was some typing mistake, P should be the set of proper normal subgroups of G.

Comment: Doesnt make any difference.  The statement you are trying to prove is wrong.